# Map some points to polygons

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have the following map in my game,

```
   x------------- 
 y +3 +5 +2 -1 -2
 | -1 +4 +2 +1 -1
 | -2 +1 -1 -1 -1
 | -1 -1 -2 -1 +2
 | +2 +2 +2 +2 +4
```

I want to draw positive points as polygons, like the following:

[image: willingimg]

How can I do that, what algorithm/way I should use?

Comment: It looks to me like you should first use a [floodfill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) and then post-process to draw your polygons.

Comment: On many graphics systems, you use `MoveTo` and `LineTo` functions to draw the edges of a polygon, or you pass an array of vertices to a function that draws the polygon.  Computing the vertex coordinates from the map is not trivial, so you may be better off creating the vertex array separately.

Comment: The top shape is incongruent: You should either have two concavities (at 2,2 and 2,3) or you should cut corners in both cases. I think you want to cut corners around concavities, otherwise your bottom shape will be quite small.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us what you need the polygons for, so I'll just assume that the polygons should visualise the islands and nothing else.

Your values seem to be a height map. where heights below zero are below sea level. You can then use this information to draw a piecewise height line for the sea level: Subdivide you map into squares where the center of your map tiles are the corner points. For any edges of these squares where one end point is above sea level and the other below, you find the point where the height is zero with linear interpolation. You have then either no, two or four such points.

If you have two points, connect them with a line. If you have four points, find out which pairs belong together by looking at the adjacent tiles and connect them. You should end up with a contour plot of your islands:

[image: A ragged archipelago]

This is your example with an artificial border of height -1 added. Because the height value isn't just taken as island/sea criterion but as physical height value, an uneven look of the shore is created. If you want your islands to look more regular, you can treat all negative heights as -1 and all positive ones as 1. You will then get a more regular look, where all points are in the middle of the squares' edges:

[image: An archipelago of 45° angles]

Note that this method does not create polygons (so my answer might miss the point entirely), because the lines are not connected. You can improve the algorithm by finding intersections for all vertical and horizontal sections of the auxiliary grid and then wander along the squares to build closed polygons, which you then may simplify as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You example is incorrect.

Algorithm can't produce different results using independent decisions on every step.

[image]

But I understood your target and possible solution is:

1.save groups of positive cells in different arrays using BFS (or floodfill, I see that there is some kind of fasion to call same things by different names). You can use negative values as border.

> N,M - size of your map
>
> board[][] - your map.
>
> visited[][] - bool array. bfs() mark cells as visited after adding them into some group
>
> groups[] - dynamic array with some structures (mb another arrays) to keep groups of cells

```
groupsCount = 0;
for row = 1..N do
    for col = 1..M do
        if( board[row][col] > 0 && !visited[row][col] ) {
            bfs(row,col,board,visited,groups[groupsCount]);
            ++groupsCount;
        }
```

2.1. use O(N^2) or O(N logN) convex hull, and you'll find the envelope with minimal perimeter for every group (just like you pulled an elastic band on a several nails).

2.2. minimal envelope may not solve you task in proper way, for example

[image]

when you want to see smth like this

[image]

In this case the possible solution is to mark positive cells adjacent to negative and run DFS with some kind of special priority. For example - "choose the closest unvisited cell". It will produce result shown above (but I'm not sure about all cases).

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the contour tracing problem. http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html

You should scan your map row by row until you find a positive value. Then use the contour tracing algorithm, joining the outline vertices,  and mark them as having been visited. Then continue the scan until you find a non-positive value (to exit of the current island), and then an unmarked positive value (the next island). And so on...